# Outlook ignores Darkmode images on HTML

Tags: microsoft-outlook, html, dark-mode

I'm creating a signature in Outlook for Windows (latest build as I write this) and my signature is not working great in dark mode, so I changed the HTML to use different images if the user is in Dark Mode:

```
   <picture>
   <source 
    srcset="DarkMode_files/image002_dark.png" 
    media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
   <img src="DarkMode_files/image002.png">
   </picture>
   </div>
```

This strategy works perfectly in Chrome as I debugged this already. However in Outlook it always uses the non-dark mode ignoring my dark mode settings.

I understand Outlook doesn't support this yet?
Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Sorry about failing to found exact documents explain whether Outlook can or can not this feature you mentioned. For now, Outlook could only support turning dark mode on or off from the Message toolbar by selecting the dark mode icon to change the message window to white or black. Personally I think, Outlook dark mode is a new feature that Outlook released, there might be some places needed to be improved. Maybe you could try to create a thread in User voice, then other users will could vote on it for you, Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version.